# Getting error Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void> in Angular5 project

Tags: typescript

Using the following Typescript code in an Angular5 project:

```
`addExpense(expense: Expense): Promise<void> {
    expense.id = uuidv4();
    const json = JSON.stringify(expense);
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    const options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers
    });
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/expenses/`, json, options)
      .toPromise();
  }
```

`

I get a compiler error `[ts] Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>.`

Answer (score 1):

Your function `addExpense()` expects to return a Promise of type void as you specified here:

```
addExpense(expense: Expense): Promise<void>
```

But you are returning a promise of type response at the end of your function.
Tell it that you will return a promise of type response by changing the first line to:

```
addExpense(expense: Expense): Promise<Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return this.http.post<void>(`${this.apiUrl}/expenses/`, json, options)
  .toPromise();
```

Comment: In the compiler you get what? (Looks like your comment got cut off.)

Comment: Hi, with this solution I got: 'Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.'

Comment: I have solved it (for now) by changing Promise<void> to Promise<any>. The compiler error goes away and I can add an expense to my backend

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it (for now) by changing `Promise<void>`to `Promise<any>`. The compiler error goes away and I can add an expense to my backend